# Is there a simple way to return two different operator types in c#

Tags: c#, return-type

I'm working on a GUI thing for a game I'm playing, and wanted to test some things out, but I've hit this strange issue where I need to return a String and a Double in the same method. My method looks like this:

```
public static modifiers(string name, double cost)
{
    //long list of Modifier strings

    //long list of Modifier costs

    return name, cost;
}
```

I know there's not much there, but I just want it do return both name and cost and I don't know how to do it. If it's a long draw out process to do this, just say it would be better just to make a second method please. I don't want to make this take longer then necessary.

Comment: [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: That looks a bit intimidating lol, (I only know the basics - like super basics (like if and for))

Comment: Probably in C# 7 this will be possible: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347

Comment: @JohnOlivas - its fairly simple. I have written an example give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

No. Basic C# syntax tells you that a return can only return one object.

THAT SAID: you can easily return a struct with 2 variables/properties. If you can accept an object (not a struct) and do not want to write your own - use a Tuple.

Comment: I just learned about structures in c++ not too hard to use, but in this case, it would be easier/faster (for me) to use a second method, thanks for the suggestion though (I don't know what a Tuple is either :P ) - I'm a noob at c# was just a bit bothered by this predicament

Comment: If you do not know what a Tuple is you never bothered to google it or learn basics (Tuple is not a .NET specific term, it is used quite often in programming). In this case, TUPLE is a set of classes (System.Tuple) with different numbers of properties (Item1, Item2 etc.) to return multiple values from a function.

Comment: I just read up on what they were, they seem far more intimidating then what seems to be worth for just a fool around program

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary` or `List<KeyValuePair<string,double>>`:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string,double>> modifiers(string name, double cost)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> lst = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();

    lst.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(name, cost));

    return lst;
}
```

Or,

```
public static Dictionary<string,double> modifiers(string name, double cost)
{
    Dictionary<string, double> lst = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    lst.Add(name, cost);

    return lst;
}
```

The retrieval process with `Dictionary` is straightforward:

```
public static Dictionary<string,double> modifiers()
{
    Dictionary<string, double> lst = new Dictionary<string,double>();

    lst.Add("test1", 10.5);
    lst.Add("test2", 10.5);
    lst.Add("test3", 10.5);
    lst.Add("test4", 10.5);

    return lst;
}


    var items = modifiers();
    double test1DoubleVal = items["test1"];
```

Comment: How would I pull from the 1st that is returned in another method? like.. string 1st.name ? or double 1st.cost ?

Comment: @JohnOlivas - see my edit - In Dictionary you access the elements value which is a double in your case with the string which is the key.

Comment: I want to understand this, I really do, but I'm not sure if it's clicking. When you call the `items["test1"]` as the array name, is that pulling the `lst.add("test1", 10.5);` or is it just pulling test1?

Comment: Its pulling the value `10.5` of the key `test1` in the Dictionary.

Comment: I think I should just try it out instead of second guessing the whole thing... ._.

Comment: If it works easily, I will. But at the moment I'm really feeling the double method for this :x